# Override main class specified in pom.xml while running jar from command line

Tags: java, maven, command-line, jar, apache-storm

I have 2 classes with main methods in a maven project.(NOT SPRING BOOT)
class A and class B

```
class A{
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        System.out.println("CLASS A");
   }
}

class B{
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        System.out.println("CLASS B");
   }
}
```

And I have specified the default main class as following in pom:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.example.A</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now when I run the project using `java -jar` from command line, the main method A executed as expected. The command I use is as follows:

```
java -jar myExample-Snapshot.jar
```

It runs the class A as expected since I have specified it under  `<mainClass>com.example.A</mainClass>` in my pom.xml.

Now I want to specify `class A` or `class B` when I execute my jar from command line. I tried the following ,

```
java -jar myExample-Snapshot.jar com.example.B
```

But it ran class A(specified in pom) with `com.example.B` as command line argument(stored in `String[] args`)

Then I tried adding main `class B` to my pom as shown below:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.example.A</mainClass>
                        <mainClass>com.example.B</mainClass> 
                    </transformer>
```

command: `java -jar myExample-Snapshot.jar com.example.A`

But this time it ran main from `class B` and completely ignored `class A`.(Again,  `com.example.A` was taken as command line argument)

Is it doable? or should I take a different approach.?

Comment: try `java -cp myExample-Snapshot.jar com.example.A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting java with the -jar parameter will cause java to look into the manifest.mf file (contained in the jar) where the main class to be executed is indicated. Obviously your maven setup creates this manifest.mf accordingly for you.

Starting java with -cp is only indicating in which jar(s) java should look up needed classes. The first non qualified parameter on the start line indicates the main class whose main() method is executed. All further parameters are passed to the main method as args[].

Comment: So if I have to provide main class while running from command line, `-cp` is the only option is it? We can not override whatever is specified in `manifest.mf`. The only way to override is `-cp`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my pom with the shade plugin, so I get a runnable exploded jar, but with no main method.

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Now I have 2 main classes:

```
public class App1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World! App 1");
    }
}
```

Now I get an exploded jar, but instead of running it as a jar I run my main with the jar added to the class path:

```
greg@greg-XPS-13-9360:~/work/double-main$ java -cp target/double-main-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.essexboy.App1
Hello World! App 1
greg@greg-XPS-13-9360:~/work/double-main$ java -cp target/double-main-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.essexboy.App2
Hello World! App 2
```

This is what the manifest looks like with a main class

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: greg
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.6.1
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_201
Main-Class: com.essexboy.App1
```